# How to refactor this code to make it cleanner ( ruby on rails )?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, refactoring

I want to refactor my code in ruby on rails.

In Order.rb I have:

```
def self.filter_price range
    case range.to_sym
    when :highest
      self.where("price > 10000")
    when :higher
      self.where(price: 5001..10000)
    when :high
      self.where(price: 1001..5000)
    when :low
      self.where(price: 501..1000)
    when :lower
      self.where(price: 1..500)
    when :lowest
      self.where(price: [0,nil])
    else
      self
    end
  end
```

In views, I have this slim html:

```
    - price_range = [ [0,nil,"lowest"], [1,500,"lower"], [501,1000,"low"], [1001,5000,"high"], [5001,10000,"higher"], [10000,">","highest"] ] 
    - (0..5).each do |i|
      tr
        - if i == 0
          th= "#{i}"
        - else
          th= "#{price_range[i][0]} - #{price_range[i][1]}"
        td.text-right= Order.filter_price(price_range[i][2]).count
          span.divider
          = with_unit (Order.filter_price(price_range[i][2]).count.to_f / Order.count.to_f * 100.0).to_i, "%"
        td.text-right
          = Order.filter_price(price_range[i][2]).select{|o| o.replied?}.count
          span.divider
          = with_unit (Order.filter_price(price_range[i][2]).select{|o| o.replied?}.count.to_f / Order.all.select{|o| o.replied?}.count.to_f * 100.0).to_i, "%"
          span.divider
          = with_unit (Order.filter_price(price_range[i][2]).select{|o| o.replied?}.count.to_f / Order.filter_price(price_range[i][2]).count.to_f * 100.0).to_i, "%"
        td.text-right
          = Order.paid.filter_price(price_range[i][2]).count
          span.divider
          = with_unit (Order.paid.filter_price(price_range[i][2]).count.to_f / Order.paid.count.to_f * 100.0).to_i, "%"
          span.margin
```

How can I remove price_range array to make the code cleaner and still get the same output result?

Can anyone help me with this, thanks in advance.

Here is what will see in views:

```
| Price  | request |      reply      | Paid  |
----------------------------------------------
|   0    |   68    | 19/15%/27%      |  5/6% |
---------------------------------------------
|1 - 500 |   19    | ....            | ....  |
----------------------------------------------
|....    |  ....   |  ....           | ....  |
```

The html code above is for looping through each row.

Comment: What is rendered in the view finally?
Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define price_range as a hash:
`price_range = {lowest: '0', low: '1 - 500', high: '1 - 500', higher: '1 - 500', highest: '10000 >'}`

You can then call `Order.filter_price(price_range.keys[0]) # lowest` and so on in a loop

`th= "#{price_range[i][0]} - #{price_range[i][1]}"`

could be then written as

`th= "#{price_range.values[i]}" # if i = 1 then price_range.values[0]: "1 - 500"`

You could also modify `order.rb` to return both 
`[Order.filter_price(price_range[i][2]).count, Order.filter_price(price_range[i][2]).select{|o| o.replied?}]` at the same time. This will further clean up your code.

Comment: Thank you. Excellent! But, is it good if we make one method in Order.rb model handles too many tasks like that?

Comment: And how I can put all the numbers in one place, for reuse purpose, so when I change the number, I can change only in one place instead of 2 places. The numbers I mean are `[ '0', '1 - 500', '501 - 1000'... ]`.

Currently, if I change the numbers, I have to change both in the hash **price_range** and in **filter_price** method in the Order.rb model.